# How I can rerun specific step on BitBucket CI?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I don't find any solutions for rerun specific step ( deploy for example )
on Bitbucket CI.
Bitbucket CI/CD interface:

[image]

In my opinion, it's a very useful feature for deploy different version of code **without rebuild project**.
**Maybe anyone knows how to do that ?**

I found an [issue on bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/14917/rerun-step-in-pipeline?_ga=2.258617737.2015811682.1562070232-1545706247.1561381004)
**If you wanna this feature you can vote for this feature**

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can have **custom** Pipelines. They can be executed independently of the status of any other pipelines of steps.

However, why would you deploy or test something without building it?

Maybe share a bit more of your process and why you want to do what you asked for, because it is not making much sense.

Good luck.

Comment: I can describe my case. I use docker registry to store my images and it very flexible to change an image from CI because it's just to click the button to deploy a project. Anyway I found [issue on community.atlassian.com](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/14917/rerun-step-in-pipeline?_ga=2.258617737.2015811682.1562070232-1545706247.1561381004)

Answer (score 0):

To create a step that can be restarted even if it was a success, you can use the deployment step.

Have a look at: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/

an example of a deployment step would be:

```
- step:
    name: Deploy app
    image: aws-cli:1.0
    deployment: production
    script:
      - something
```

Note: You have to go to your pipeline settings and create a deployment called production in our case.

The result will be something like:

[image]